# JQgrid: fix column set

Tags: jqgrid

I'm facing the following problem: I can't fix column order in JQgrid.
As you know you can change columns order using drag and drop feature... but in my case I have to fix the order. Does anybody know how to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you use `sortable:true` instead of default `sortable:false`? In case of `sortable:false` the user can't drag and drop the columns.

Comment: Oh, yes! The problem is fixed. Thanks!